# Java Generics Name type parameter without requiring it

Tags: java, generics, types

Suppose I have some `class Edge<A, B>` with subclasses that provide the parameterization, e.g `class MyEdge extends Edge<MyNodeType, MyOtherNodeType>`

I am currently declaring another class that uses `Edge`s as so:

```
class EdgeHolder<E extends Edge<A, B>, A, B> {
    A getFirstNode();
    B getSecondNode();
}
```

and using it as such:

```
EdgeHolder<MyEdge, MyNodeType, MyOtherNodeType> var = ...
```

This feels awfully clunky, especially since `MyNodeType` and `MyOtherNodeType` are specified in `MyEdge`'s definition.

I'd love to be able to *name* the parameters `A` and `B` in the definition of `EdgeHolder` because I need compile-time type-checking on its methods' return type, but I don't want to have to specify `A` and `B` when I declare variables of type `EdgeHolder`.

Is there a way to do this (or something like it)?

If not, why not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382912/extract-generic-types-from-extended-generic

Comment: Why do you need EdgeHolder in first place? Why do you need EdgeHolder for each particular type if you're going to delegate anyway?

Comment: @bashnesnos I was trying to make the example in the question as simple as possible, but it's actually effectively a collection of multiple edges.

Comment: @assylias the second answer in the linked provides a very pragmatical explanation on why it's impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no type alias in Java, but you can try use this approach.

```
class Edge<A, B> {
    class MyEdgeHolder<E extends Edge<A, B>> extends EdgeHolder<E, A, B> {}
}
class MyEdge extends Edge<MyNodeType, MyOtherNodeType> {
    class MyEdgeHolder extends Edge<MyNodeType, MyOtherNodeType>.MyEdgeHolder<MyEdge> {}
}
```

Use it like this:

```
MyEdge.MyEdgeHolder var;
Edge<?, ?>.MyEdgeHolder<?> var2 = var;
```

This approach is very limited, but may fit your specific scenario.

Comment: hm, thanks. That only partially mitigates my problem as anytime I wanted to pass around an `EdgeHolder` (without knowing what type it is) I'd still have to do the declaration. This also means I'd be defining subclasses of `EdgeHolder` for every possible Edge type, which is a bit unfeasible

Comment: I slightly extended my idea.

Comment: your update is perfect and set me down the path for exactly what I need - thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The best idea I could come to reduce typing yet preserve type checking at compile time:

```
class Edge<A, B> {
  A src;
  B dest;
}

class EdgeHolderBase<A, B, E extends Edge<A,B>> {
  Edge<A,B> in_hold;
}

// explicit specialization of generics
class MyEdge
extends Edge<Integer, Long> {

}
class MyEdgeHolder
extends EdgeHolderBase<Integer, Long, MyEdge> {
// --- One off excessive typing -- ^

}
```

Comment: Effectively the same as @talex's answer, with the same shortcomings (still have to declare `EdgeHolderBase<A, B, E>` anytime you don't know what kind of edge you're dealing with; have to make a custom holder for every type), but it does help cleanup the code a bit in some places. thanks

Comment: @ThomasShields assylas have linked a nice explanation (in the OP comments) on why you can't do better than this. Particularly, I like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382912/extract-generic-types-from-extended-generic#answer-2401801)